# Java printing an object, encapsulation

Tags: java, class, object, hash, encapsulation

I need to print  3 variables using encapsulation, and I cannot modify the main class.

The main Class declares variables[cylinders, make, owner] and wants to create and print an object with the parameters as such:

```
System.out.println (new Vehicle (cylinders, make, owner)); //create Vehicle object
```

The Object, is supposed to take in the variables and print out a simple sentence.

Now, my code 'works':

```
import java.util.*;
public class Vehicle{
int var;
int var2;
double var3;
String var4;
String var5;
String tots;

public Vehicle (int cylinders, String make,String owner){
var2=cylinders;
var4=make;
var5=owner;
System.out.println(var4+", "+ var2+ " cylinders, "+"owned by "+ var5 );
}
}
```

It prints the sentence in the main program, but when it prints, it prints a weird value after, "Vehicle@3d434234", which seems to be the class name followed by some sort of hash/hex value.

If I take out my print statement

```
System.out.println(var4+", "+ var2+ " cylinders, "+"owned by "+ var5 );
```

Then it will just return the "Vehicle@3d434234"

How can I stop it from printing the hash value of the class,

Please keep in mind I cannot modify

```
System.out.println (new Vehicle (cylinders, make, owner));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Override `toString` method in `Vehicle` class.

Comment: Save yourself lots of trouble and get in the habit of picking descriptive names for fields and variables. Using names like `var`, `var2`, etc. is really a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the `toString` method for it:

Write this method in your `Vehicle` class:

```
public String toString(){

 return var4+", "+ var2+ " cylinders, "+"owned by "+ var5;
}
```

Note that the variables `var4`, etc are the variables defined in your class `Vehicle`.

Comment: thanks! it seems to be working now :),

Is it better to make a toString usually?

Comment: @gunter - Only if you might want to print a meaningful representation of the object. That's often useful for debugging (until you learn to use a debugger).

Comment: Yes whenever you are going to print your object, if `toString` is not overriden than you will see this kind of string `Vehicle@3d434234`

Comment: The default implementation (which gives you that odd output) just tells you the class name and the `hashCode`, which by default is arbitrarily assigned. It's almost always a good idea to write your own `toString()` that provides output describing the contents of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override toString method for the class whose object you want to print in a String notation.

like

```
class Name{ 
       private String name;

        public Name(String name){
         this.name=name;
       }


       public String toString(){
          return this.name;
      }
       public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println(new Name("yourname"))   //output "yourname"    
       }

    }
```